# java.lang.nosuchmethoderror no method android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When i try to run the app from the eclipse my apps runs successfully, but when i try to generate the apk and deploy it into the device i have been getting following exception can anyone help me in this issue.

```
09-23 16:49:20.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20952): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-469
09-23 16:49:20.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20952): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='browserNotifyMessage' signature='(Lcom/godbtech/sync/GBrowserNotifyMessageEvt;)V' in class Lcom/godbtech/sync/GNativeSync;
09-23 16:49:20.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20952):    at com.godbtech.sync.GNativeSync._startSync(Native Method)
09-23 16:49:20.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20952):    at com.godbtech.sync.GNativeSync.run(Unknown Source)
09-23 16:49:20.390: E/AndroidRuntime(20952):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-23 16:49:20.445: E/android.os.Debug(2141): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Comment: Are you using Proguard? If so, you must make sure this class is not deleted by Proguard.

Comment: no i am not using any proguard i have add the jar file in the lib folder and added to the build path. But when i try to run the app with eclipse i am able to run but this issue is only if i create the apk and deploy it to the device